# Deploy Django project: folder/project structure

Tags: django, deployment, project-structure

My django project in eclipse has this project structure:

main-project-folder/

```
                 src/
                        main-app/
                                 app1/
                                 app2/
                                 settings.py
                                 manage.py
                                 urls.py
                                 __init__.py
                 media/
                 templates/
```

Can i deploy the project with this structure? In other words, is right way to put src and other folders (media, tempaltes, etc.) in the root folder of my server (where my domain is linked)?

Like:

my-server-folder/

```
             src/
             media/
             ...
```

I imagine that in my-server-folder i should put the entry point of project, but in my project i haven't an entry point in main-project-folder, or does django automatically redirect to an entry point of src/main-app folder (i think that it doesn't because i don't find any options that say to django to do it)?

Comment: I would think the location of media and templates depends on what you've configured in settings.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  That's a fine directory structure.

Keep in mind your web server isn't going to know what to do with the Django project unless you tell it.  If your web server is Apache (which it probably is if you don't know) look here for instructions to set it up to run the Django app:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

And here for WSGI:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

Django apps aren't like PHP where you just upload them to the web server and they work.